# Create Pivot table by using Autoit

Tags: autoit

Am trying to create pivot table by using Auto it tool, can anyone help to complete this code,need to add field in Columns , Rows and Value

below code just adding field in Filters

```
$oExcel = ObjCreate("Excel.Application")
$oExcel.Visible = 1
$oExcel.WorkBooks.Open ("C:\AR\Deptwise AR-20.03.2017.xlsx")
$test = $oExcel.ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(1,"A1:Y11795",1) 
$oExcel.Sheets.Add
$test2 = $oExcel.Range("A1:Y11795")
$oExcel.ActiveSheet.PivotTables.Add($test,$test2,"GCI")
$oExcel.Application.ActiveSheet.PivotTables("GCI").PivotFields("GCI").Orientation = 3
$oExcel.ActiveSheet.PivotTables ("PivotTable5" ).PivotCache.Refresh
```

Comment: Did you try to record your things with the macro recorder and then use that code?

Comment: No,but how i will connect autoit and macro both together?

Comment: VBA and Autoit is very similar. Just copy the VB code to Scite and change it to Autoit syntax.

Comment: Hi I have tried but still its not working, can you show me how to change Autoit syntax

Comment: Sure, what does your excel code look like?

Comment: How attached code file in this forum? code is too long to paste in comment box

Comment: Maybe try this : https://pastebin.com/